# Get d values of Path within brush

Tags: javascript, path, d3.js

I'm playing with the following example, and I've made it to a single line chart. 
http://bl.ocks.org/gniemetz/4618602.

In the example when you brush on mini chart the main chart gets scaled for those points. I want that behaviour and want fill those data points on the interval of some seconds. The blocking point is how do I select those points from Path so that I can fill them.

I've brush's start and end index

```
startIndex = brush.extent()[0]; endIndex = brush.extent()[1]
```

Now I want to select the path that comes under these range. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

The extent of the brush gives you what you need. You can use it to filter the data you have and then operate on the subset that designates the selection:

```
var sel = elements.filter(function(d) {
  return d.value >= brush.extent()[0] && d.value <= brush.extent()[1];
});

sel.attr("stroke", "purple");
```

where `elements` contains the selection of the DOM elements that you want to operate on and have the respective data bound.

Comment: This would be whatever the value for the x axis is called in your code. `d.Uhrzeit` in the example you've linked to.

Comment: I just did that but once I say selection.attr("fill","grey") that selection is of my data values and it is not having attr option.

Comment: Sorry, should have been more precise here -- `data` refers to the DOM elements. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I guess I got it..
main.select("line0").data(selection).attr("fill","red");

Comment: But there is very weird behaviour, once I fill the path point and move the brush around, the entire chart disappears :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42571/discussion-between-sadik-and-lars-kotthoff)